# A simple networking question, but not for me!

Tags: subnet

I am attempting to get a decent understanding of simple networking as I am opening a new business alongside an existing and attempt to do the IT work myself, seeing as we don't have a great demand in that department.

My existing network is below as *Network 1* and I want to ensure our new network at a different location is completely separate so that when we eventually introduce a VPN there won't be any issues with regards to it. Can someone confirm that the below are totally separate and don't interfere with each other?

**Network 1:**

```
Gateway: 192.168.100.1
Range: 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.100.255
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

**Network 2:**

```
Gateway: 192.168.101.1
Range: 192.168.101.1 - 192.168.101.255
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how these networks are currently connected?

Comment: They're not connected. I just want to make sure that the two setups that I've put above would not interfere with each other when we eventually introduce a VPN.

Comment: You shouldn't have any implementation issues with that.

Comment: Many home consumer networks default to 192.168.1 or even 192.168.100.  Though your two network are unique, I would avoid the 192.168 block completely for business if your contemplating VPN in the future as remote access users could have conflicts with their home subnets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `192.168.100.0/24` and `192.168.101.0/24` ranges are on different networks, you won't have any issues when you do decide to setup a connection between the two.